# Flutter Update ListView.builder based on a variable

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, setstate

I have a pretty simple problem. When I change a variable that gets assigned from a get request to my server, I want the listview.builder to rerender the screen. This is what my screen looks like currently:
[image: screen]
(each news article (separated by a white sizedbox) is rendered based on a variable called _posts - when this variable gets updated I want all the news widgets to update)

EDIT: For example when the user clicks the heart icon, I send a request to the server to tell it that the user liked the news article, and when it comes back with the updated liked list, I want the icon to be colored in or not based on what the server returns

MORE INFO

- The widgets are inside a listview.builder
- My class extends a stateful widget
- The server returns a json object
- I've been working on this for 8+ hours and can't figure it out

Thank you so much!

EXAMPLE CODE:
This is what my heart icon looks like. When the user clicks on the heart icon, it tells the server that the post is not liked anymore, and gets the updated liked list. However, when I do a setState(() => {liked=(SERVER RESPONSE LIKED)}), it doesn't update the view.

```
Icon(
liked.contains(_posts[index]['id'].toString())
? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border, color: Colors.white))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call GET API again after getting response on tap of heart icon & don't forgot to clear current list or else you will get duplicate data. **Use ternary operator (condition ? Text("Red Heart") : Text("Normal Heart"),)**
Also try to share some code, it will help me to understand what exactly has done.

Comment: I added some code and some more details. I still am stumped on how to fix it. Thank you so much!